# I disabled my touchpad, and now there's no option to reenable it on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, lenovo, settings, system-settings

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop(Lenovo Z400).  Last night I disabled the touchpad, because I was using external mouse. Today I tried reenabling the touchpad, but there isn't that option any more in the mouse settings.  I am just seeing the setting for Primary Button and Double Click speeds. Where did my touchpad go?

Answer (score 0):

Try [touchpad extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/131/touchpad-indicator/) to re-enable and control your touchpad.